# Zend_Db_Table: What happens when insert results in an error?

Tags: database, zend-framework, error-handling, exception

This is probably an easy question to answer, but I don't see it mentioned in the documentation...

What happens when insert results in an error? Is an exception thrown? What type? I'm trying to understand what would happen when trying to insert duplicate data in a column that is unique.

So I feel like I need to do some checking first...

```
protected function _emailAlreadySubscribed($email)
{
    $select = $this->_model->select()->where('email = ?', $email);
    $rows = $table->fetchAll($select);
    if ($rows->count()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this the correct way to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, checking to see if the email already exists is *not* a valid solution.  Someone else could insert a duplicate value after your check but before your `INSERT`.  The only solution is to lock the entire table.

When you violate a unique key in `Zend_Db_Table::insert()`, a `Zend_Db_Statement_Exception` (or a subclass thereof) is thrown.

See also [MySQL Insert: Test first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440131/mysql-insert-test-first/440165#440165)

Comment: How high is the probability that two users insert the same email within a few miliseconds into the same table where the email column is unique? I see your point but I do think, using an isUnique validator does the job fine and is a valid approach. If the case you describe happens (p=.00000000001?) you will get an error, and?

Comment: After a couple of thoughts I have to admit that maybe it's stupid to do it the 99% sure way if you can just as well do it the 100% sure way... but I still doubt that such a violation has ever happened with emails.

Comment: will there be any way to tell that the exception was thrown because the entry is a duplicate, versus some unknown error?

Comment: yes, there will be some sort of duplicate key or duplicate entry exception.

Comment: Right, and if you don't catch the exception and handle it in some constructive way, it'll spew an exception across your application's white screen.  IMHO any exception, no matter how unlikely, must be handled, to prevent that user experience.

Comment: I'd agree that two different people are unlikely to enter the same email address simultaneously.  But the *same* person may be pretty likely to be confused about the user interface, and try to submit the same form from two different windows or something.  This kind of thing does happen!

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with Zend Framework to try and detect DB exceptions and handle them. Unfortunately, once you have caught the exception, the getCode() method always seems to return '0', so I ended up using the following code to check for duplicates:

```
try { 
    $model->insert($data);
    $added++; 
} catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
    if(strstr($e->getMessage(), '1062 Duplicate')) {
        // duplicate
        $duplicates++;
    } else {
        // general error
        $errors++;
    }
}
```

Not the most graceful code I know, so if anyone knows how to handle these exceptions better or has an exception code reference please chip in!

Answer (score 0):

For inserts, I make sure my db table has proper indexes (in this case, a unique index on emailAddress) and then I just wrap my insert in a try/catch block.

I let the DB tell me if it's a dupe rather than checking first.

Insert will throw exceptions when the database fails.  You can then check why the database failed using the exception and display the appropriate messaging to your user.